# Dapper and Nested Transactions

Tags: .net, sql-server, transactions, transactionscope, dapper

Is it possible to specify a **nested** transaction as an IDbTransaction parameter, when using a Dapper method?

I want to commit an inner transaction via Dapper, with all data and associated locks to be released and available **only** to the outer transaction, with all outer locks still in place before the outer transaction is committed.

See this for a concrete example: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189336(v=sql.105).aspx

I am using SQL Server 2008, if that helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dapper uses ado.net transactions. Also, since many ado.net providers support ambient transactions (TransactionScope), this is usually supported - but requires no extra code. If you can do what you want with ado.net transactions: fine. If you can do what you want with TSQL: fine - just issue the appropriate commands. Really it comes down to: can you do that from ado.net?

It would, for example, be worth trying a stored procedure with explicit transaction inside a connection with the connection's BeginTransaction.